# how to insert a required value prestashop?

Tags: php, html, prestashop

I manage a site via Prestashop, I've been trying for several days to enter a condition for my code but I can't, that's why I'm asking for your help :)

It is to put "required" for the choice of gender on my site "man" or "woman" to make the selection obligatory. (image attached)
[gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11zFg.png)

When I replay this: 'required' => true

[required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnYLU.png)

I get an error when I validate the form like this:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xljSW.png)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug mode, and you will see the exact error instead of the 500 error message.
This will help you find a solution.

If you are not able to fix it knowing the error message, then extend your original question with the error message, and we can help you more efficiently

Comment: Thank you for your reply 

Thank you for your reply 

You have my answer down bel